# How do raise exception if all elements of numpy array are not floats?

Tags: python, numpy

Just as the title says, I want to raise an exception when I send in an input A that should be an array containing floats. That is, if A contains at least one item that is not a float it should return an TypeError.

Comment: Any thing you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numbers in a numpy array have the same dtype. So you can quickly check what dtype the array has by looking at `array.dtype`. If this is float or float64 then every single item in the array will be of type float.

Numpy can also create arrays with mixed dtypes similar to normal python lists but then `array.dtype=np.object`, in this case anything can be in the array elements. But in my experience there are only a few cases where you actually need `np.object`

To check if the dtype is either of `float16`,`float32`, `float64` use

`if not issubclass(array.dtype.type, numpy.float):
    raise TypeError('float type expected')`